# Linq-to-SQL: foreign key not accessible until transaction is committed

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I've found that with Linq-to-SQL, when you create a new object you can not access a foreign-key member until you have called `SubmitChanges` on the context the new object is being "created with." I understand, of course, that the FK doesn't really exist until you've committed the new object to the database - but it seems that the information is there to allow the lookup to work. Take, for example, the code below.

```
public Course Create(string name, int teacherID)
{
     using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        Course c = new Course();

        c.Name = name;
        c.TeacherID = teacherID; //FK here, assume the value references a valid Teacher.
        context.Courses.InsertOnSubmit(c); //c now has a context it can use.

        //Try to do some validation here, before commiting the Course to the database.
        //c.Teacher will be null here, leading to an exception.
        if (c.Teacher.FirstName.Equals("Phil"))
            throw new ApplicationException("Phil quit last year."); //Throwing here would cause the transaction to never commit, good.

        context.SubmitChanges();

        //Email the teacher.
        SendEmail(c.Teacher.EmailAddress); //c.Teacher is no longer null, this would work fine.
    }
}
```

The above code has some comments that should illustrate what I'm asking. My question is basically this:

**Why must I first `SubmitChanges` in order to lookup a value based on a primitive ID (FK) which is already set on the object?**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `c.Teacher` *would* be null there.  Linq-To-Sql does not provide any mechanism to load an entity based on a manually populated foreign-key column (at least, not until you get to `SubmitChanges`).  Certainly it would lazy-load if you had pulled the entity from the db -- but here you are creating it.  Either pass in the `teacher` entity (instead of the id) or manually fetch the entity and set that instead:

```
c.Teacher = teacher
```

Instead of

```
c.TeacherID = teacherID
```

Comment: Passing in the entity gets messy if it's not from the same DataContext and I was hoping to not have to pre-fetch **every** FK entity. But, alas, I may have to do that. Thanks.

Comment: You only have to pre-fetch them if you actually need to grab data off of them. (in this case you are, obviously)   May I ask why separate datacontexts are involved when calling one method from another? The usual model is one datacontext per thread/request/etc.   Otherwise, you could pass in the entity, but *still* set the `EntityID`.  Just make sure you reference the parameter passed in, rather than the entity properties.

Comment: The real reason for the question is if you have a create method for each entity which sets the properties based on the passed-in parameters and then calls some `Validate(theObject)` method to do some validation on its properties **before** committing it to the database. That's why I said "pre-fetch every FK," since you won't know which ones the `Validate` method will need to check.

Comment: And the reason for more than one DataContext is multi-threading/parallel processing. I do prefer to pass the entities around rather than keep fetching them but as I mentioned, working with more than one DataContext can get messy.

Comment: @Josh, I understand what you're saying.  You want `.Insert` to do what `SubmitChanges` does -- sync up the entity.  But it doesn't do that, and unfortunately there's not a whole lot you can do about it.  In principle, if you were generating the entities yourself (via code-gen) you could conceivably modify the setters of the the ID properties so that they also set the underlying `EntityRef`'s `source` property to an `IQueryable` that you "prefetch" for it.  And since it's an `IQueryable` it would honor lazy-loading and so wouldn't truly fetch it if it didn't get accessed.  Not trivial, though.

Comment: I am using a code generator (http://www.quantumconceptscorp.com/Products/CodeGenerator.aspx) so I can change the entities as needed. Could setting the `.Entity` property of the `EntityRef<>` in this manner have some side effects? That's a good solution if it doesn't.

Comment: @Josh, you would actually set the `source` field of `EntityRef` (via the constructor that takes an `IEnumerable`).  This is how Linq-To-Sql implements lazy-loading when you fetch from the database.  So you could modify the code-gen for the FK ID properties, and have it set the `EntityRef` field for the corresponding entity property to a `new EntityRef(dataContext.YourEntities.Where(x => ...))`.  The one catch, of course, is that you very likely have no reference to the `DataContext` when in the setter of your ID prop, and I'm not sure the best way to give it a handle to it.